# what the ':S' meaning in 'who' result

Tags: server, who

when i check who using the server with command `who` it show :

```
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/0    182.253.177.249  19:33    0.00s  0.05s  0.00s w
root     pts/6    103.24.104.122:S 14:39    8.00s  0.03s  0.03s /bin/bash
```

the first one is my ip address, the second one is unknown with strange `:S` attached to it, can somebody explain to me what the meaning of it ? thanx

Comment: :S means Server

Comment: do you mean my server ? but my server ip address is different with that

Comment: check this http://myip.ms/info/whois/103.24.104.122 , it shows that the said ip is online from windows 7 x64 , i guess someone from windows is accessing your system

Comment: ah i see that explain a lot, i guess it was the company where the server reside, about that `:S` thing do you mean it was the real server ip (not vm)?

Comment: That looks like output from `w`, not output from `who`. If you are actually using `who` there, could you include the full command line you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have to guess that :S is a sticky IP.

It is a cross between dynamic IP and static IP, a sticky IP is assigned dynamically, but hangs onto your broadband modem as long as you don't have to reset it.

> What most cable poviders will use is what is called A sticky dynamic
>   IP address or sticky IP is an informal term used by cable and DSL
>   Internet access subscribers to describe a dynamically assigned IP
>   address that does not change often. The addresses are usually assigned
>   with the DHCP protocol. Since the modems are usually powered-on for
>   extended periods of time, the address leases are usually set to long
>   periods and simply renewed upon expiration. If a modem is turned off
>   and powered up again before the next expiration of the address lease,
>   it will most likely receive the same IP address.<sup>[DSLReports](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/remark,23608909)</sup>